# Background color on specific dates using JCalendar

Tags: java, netbeans, jcalendar

Im trying to set specific dates in my JCalendar in a different color depending on if there is something planned for that date in my database, the date is stored as"yyyy-MM-dd" in the database, I've seen similar posts here on stackOverflow but I just cant get it to work.

I'm not sure how "component[day].setBackground(Color.green)" works like and how I can set it to only dates that has something planned for them in the database

```
    public void kalender() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    int offset = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    int mon = kalender.getMonthChooser().getMonth() + 1;

    int yr = kalender.getYearChooser().getYear();

    JPanel jPanel = kalender.getDayChooser().getDayPanel();

    Component component[] = jPanel.getComponents();

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
     String kalenderdatum = format.format(kalender.getDate());
     System.out.println(kalenderdatum);



    String sql2 = "SELECT DATUM FROM MOTE";
    try {
        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql2);

        while (rs.next()) {
            String datumet = rs.getString("DATUM");



            String aret = datumet.substring(0, 4);
            int year = Integer.parseInt(aret);

            String manaden = datumet.substring(5,7);
            int month = Integer.parseInt(manaden);

            String dagen = datumet.substring(8,10);
            int day = Integer.parseInt(dagen);

            if(yr == year && mon == month)
            {

                component[day].setBackground(Color.green);
            }

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution that uses the JCalendar API is to create your own instance of `IDateEvaluator` and checks if a date has anything "special" about it.

**1. Converting**

First I suggest getting your dates (`yyyy-MM-dd`) into a list and convert them to `Date` objects. For example:

```
List<String> mysqlDates = Arrays.asList("2019-02-14", "2019-03-06"); // Assume you've got this info somehow
List<Date> specialDates = convertToDates(mysqlDates);
```

With the help of the following function:

```
public static List<Date> convertToDates(List<String> dateStrings) throws ParseException {
    List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<>();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    for (String dateString : dateStrings) {
        dates.add(df.parse(dateString));
    }

    return dates;
}
```

**2. Create your SpecialDateEvaluator**

Then you need to create your own date evaluator that takes in the `Date` objects that are going to be handled differently. A simple example would be the following:

```
public class SpecialDateEvaluator implements IDateEvaluator {

    private final List<Date> specialDates;

    public SpecialDateEvaluator(List<Date> specialDates) {
        this.specialDates = specialDates;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSpecial(Date date) {
        for (Date d : specialDates) {
            if (d.equals(date)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Color getSpecialForegroundColor() {
        return Color.black;
    }

    @Override
    public Color getSpecialBackroundColor() {
        return Color.red;
    }

    @Override
    public String getSpecialTooltip() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isInvalid(Date date) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Color getInvalidForegroundColor() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Color getInvalidBackroundColor() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getInvalidTooltip() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**3. Utilize the date evaluator**

To utilize the evaluator you need to add it to the `JDayChooser`, taking in the list of `Date` objects and then setting the `Calendar` again to refresh the view. For example:

```
JCalendar c = new JCalendar();
c.getDayChooser().addDateEvaluator(new SpecialDateEvaluator(specialDates));
c.setCalendar(Calendar.getInstance());
```

To see a full example of this (with a main method), see [this example gist](https://gist.github.com/Ondkloss/b5c224d260d26eded0e355766c838ec5).